# How to fix Cors error Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I have a spring boot rest application and I am not using Spring security. My rest service looks like this

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthenticationService {
    ...
    @GetMapping(path = "/getUser")
    public JSONObject getUser() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I call the API from a REST application using axios get. Everything works fine locally.

But when the application is deployed on cloud as a docker image, I get the 403 error
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Even when I add a CorsConfiguration file I get the same error.

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() 
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("Accept", "Origin", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-XSRF-Header")
                .allowCredentials(true);
                }
        };
    }
}
```

I have spent a lot of time to find a solution for this but somehow it isn't working.

Comment: And also when I add the CorsConfiguration file,local stops working and throws Cors error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fixed by adding spring security

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a bean works fine for me:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer, WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final Environment env;
    private final MyProperties properties;

    public WebConfigurer(Environment env, MyProperties properties) {
        this.env = env;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = properties.getCors();
        if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/management/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v3/api-docs", config);
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

}
```

Yaml properties:

```
  # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile
  cors:
    allowed-origins: '*'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

Comment: Do you use some kind of filter before authentication? (I assume you are using basic auth?). If yes try adding it http.csrf().disable().addFilterBefore(corsFilter, MyAuthFilter.class). Also, your (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) WebSecurity should ignore OPTIONS header:  I am using spring security, but I think it should be similar: web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")

Comment: Filter which I am using is: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: I am not using spring security. There is an Oauth2 client defined for the rest api. All the urls are https. But the same code works locally  as well as on a VM with http . Don't know if this makes a difference.